# Why this the result of this summation code wrong?

Tags: python

I was following a tutorial online and I did the same as the video but it gives me a different result?

```
total1 = 0

for b in range(1,5):
    total1 += b

print(b)
```

The total should be 10, but instead I get 4. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Did you mean ‘print(total1)’?

Comment: Should you not be printing total1? Why are you printing b?

Comment: @Meto It wasn't caused by typo. In the loop, the total1 increases, and he printed the wrong thing. Thats all

Comment: print total1 not b !!!!

Comment: Yeah you’re right! I was printing the wrong thing. Thanks guys!

Comment: @Kovacic95 Then could you accept and upvote my answer? Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should be printing total1, instead of b.

This would be your code:

```py
total1 = 0

for b in range(1, 5):
    total1 += b

print(total1)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why is this downvoted? :(

Comment: I don't know I gave you a thumb up! but for some reasons it doesnt count. thanks for your input anyway.

Comment: @Kovacic95 Click the check that is greyed out

Comment: There's a message popping out saying that I have to wait. I think they closed the topic.

Comment: @Kovacic95 Do it in 5 minutes, if you don't mind. Thanks!